# Combining raster (netcdf) data and discrete data based on corresponding date and x, y coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, netcdf, python-xarray

Disclaimer, I am no Python expert, I usually use it for mostly dataviz and simple calcs.

I have a netCDF file of sea ice concentration data (from NSIDC) where the coordinates are time (daily average), x, and y. The ice concentration data is in 25 square kilometer pixels. I also have my own discrete dataset from a research cruise track, where I also have dimensions time, x, and y. I want to associate a given sampling station from the cruise track with the sea ice concentration at that given time and location.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
x = df['x'].values
y = df['y'].values
date = pd.date_range(start = '2021-05-24', end = '2021-06-05')

ice = []
for t in date:
    for i in x:
        for j in y:
            SIC = sliced_ds.F17_ICECON.where((sliced_ds.time == t &
                               (x > (sliced_ds.x + i*25)) & (x < (sliced_ds.x +(i+1)*25)) & 
                               (y > (sliced_ds.y + j*25)) & (sliced_ds.y < (y+(j+1)*25))))
            ice.append((date,x,y,SIC))
```

And I get an error saying the "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (395,) (88,)", because my discrete data (the df) has 395 points but there's only 88 data points for x in the sea ice dataset... how can I make this work?

Comment: It's hard to provide a specific solution without access to the data. But you could check out my nctoolkit package, which has a specific method for handling situations like this https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchpoint.html